# Switched off device is kept charging for a long time? Is this okay?

Tags: battery, charging, battery-life

Is it harmful for a switched off device to be kept charging for a long time? If yes, I would like to know why. (Not a very deep explanation but just a plain explanation as I am not an expert).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not altogether harmful, because once the battery is fully charged, it stops receiving more current automatically. This is true because most laptops can be use plugged in while fully charged to save the juice.
But however, its good practice to unplug your device once its full because some non-li-ion batteries tend to decrease in efficiency due to contactly being plugged in while full.
Hope this answered your question...

Comment: Actually I read somewhere that it is not very ok to charge a switched off device, it creates more pressure on the device so I was asking !.

Comment: Possibly, but come to think of it, most of the electronic devices are charged while off... Plus most devices tend to be affected by power surge while charged ON than not...

Comment: Oh ! Thats also true

Comment: Right... Thumbs up...

Comment: @Hiren you could help mark my answer and give upvote . Would appreciate